# Self-adjoint bounded operator with finite spectrum implies diagonalisable?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras, self-adjoint-operators

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint bounded operator on a not-necessarily finite dimensional Hilbert space.

Suppose $T$ has finite spectrum. Does it follow that the elements of the spectrum are eigenvalues, and the operator diagonlisable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can calculate the spectral projection for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ by integrating the resolvent in a small contour around $\lambda$ that avoids all of the other eigenvalues
$$P_\lambda = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C (T-z I)^{-1} \, dz.$$
The Hilbert space will then be the direct sum of the spectral subspaces corresponding to the spectral projections. Isolated elements of the spectrum are always eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you Brian 

Comment: Does this speak to discrete spectrum?

Comment: I think so. A self-adjoint operator with a finite spectrum is a special case of self-adjoint operators with compact resolvent. You might want to look up the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators with compact resolvent.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is also tagged "C$^*$-algebras", I'll answer in that setting. If $\sigma(T)=\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$, we can construct continuous functions (polynomials, even) $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ with $f_k(\lambda_j)=\delta_{kj}$. Then $\sum_k\lambda_kf_k(t)=t$, and functional calculus gives us
$$
T=\sum_k\lambda_kf_k(T),
$$
where $f_1(T),\ldots,f_n(T)$ are pairwise orthogonal projections.

Comment: Thank you Martin. You're a maestro with this stuff.

Comment: Glad I could help!